# Android SQLite Database with Multiple Columns

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So I'm trying to make a database which has name, calorie, and protein columns.  Here is the create statement:

```
public class SQLHelp extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Food.db";
    static final String TABLE_FOOD = "food";
    static final String NAME_COLUMN = "FoodName";
    static final String CALORIE_COLUMN = "Calorie";
    static final String PROTEIN_COLUMN = "Protein";
    static final String FAT_COLUMN = "Fat";
    static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";

    public SQLHelp(Context c){
        super(c, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String makeTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FOOD + "("
                + NAME_COLUMN + " TEXT," + CALORIE_COLUMN + " INTEGER,"
                + PROTEIN_COLUMN + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(makeTable);      
    }
```

The values are added to the database with the following method:

```
public void createFood(Food f) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SQLHelp.CALORIE_COLUMN, f.getCalories());
    values.put(SQLHelp.PROTEIN_COLUMN, f.getProtein());
    values.put(SQLHelp.NAME_COLUMN, f.getName());
    database.insert(SQLHelp.TABLE_FOOD, null,
            values);
}
```

When it tries to add, LogCat gives me an SQLiteException saying that the Protein column doesn't exist.  What's even stranger is that when I run the code with commented out protein lines, everything works just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code for your `Food` class, espeically the getters that you are using here. Also post the stack trace from logcat, at least until the first line that shows a method name from something you wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DB helper only updates the database when you update the version number. You are running your version #1 DB which did not include those columns.

if you change your version to 2 it will reflect your newly added columns

```
 public SQLHelp(Context c){
        super(c, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2); //note the 2 here
    }
```